# How can I ignore DS_Store settings for a given drive?

Tags: macos, finder

I regularly use a network drive (using SMB), along with a bunch of other Mac users. Because those other Macs leave the window view settings in .DS_Store files, I'm constantly having my windows open using other people's last-view settings. Is there any way I can somehow tell the Finder to ignore .DS_Store settings for a given volume?

(I know there's a way I can stop *my* system from leaving .DS_Store files, but setting that same preference on every Mac that might access the volume is not an option.)

Answer (score 1):

Other than using the terminal command

```
sudo find /<volume> -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;
```

and running it with cron on a regular schedule, you could use FolderWasher, and clean up the volume whenever you wish.

http://sw.ixoft.com/folderwasher/